# mysql trigger(insert field after update)

Tags: mysql, database, triggers

I have a problem where the table transaksi is not updated when i inserted the table temp
here is the trigger code,thanks for your cooperation

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `tr1` ;
CREATE DEFINER = `root`@`localhost` TRIGGER `tr1` AFTER UPDATE ON `temp` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN DECLARE user varchar( 50 ) ;
DECLARE barang varchar( 100 ) ;
DECLARE hg int( 10 ) ;
DECLARE st int( 10 ) ;
SELECT username(
)
INTO user;
SELECT nama_produk(
)
INTO barang;
SELECT harga(
)
INTO hg;
INSERT INTO transaksi( id, username, barang_pesan, total )
VALUES (
"", user, barang, harga
);
END
```

Comment: The trigger code does not look correct. In which table `user,barang,harga` belongs to.

Comment: SELECT username(
)
INTO user;
SELECT nama_produk(
)
INTO barang;
SELECT harga(
)
INTO hg;
INSERT INTO transaksi( id, username, barang_pesan, total )
VALUES (
"", user, barang, harga
);

Comment: I try to remove () and replace the value from harga to hg but still not working.

Comment: SELECT username

INTO user;
SELECT nama_produk

INTO barang;
SELECT harga

INTO hg;
INSERT INTO transaksi( id, username, barang_pesan, total )
VALUES (
"", user, barang, hg
);

Answer (score 0):

You must create another trigger with same code to `after insert` event

```
CREATE DEFINER = `root`@`localhost` TRIGGER `tr1` AFTER INSERT ON `temp` ...
```